# "There is a pen on the desk." vs. "A pen is on the desk."

Tags: sentence-structure

> A pen is on the desk.

Can I say it in this way, too?

> There is a pen on the desk

Do they have the same meaning? If not, what's the difference?

Comment: What do you think the meaning is?

Comment: For a long long time , I have thought that they are the same, but the second one is more common and used by natives most of the time .Today I doubted.

Answer (score 1):

If you were patting your pockets looking for a pen, and I saw you doing it, it would be natural for me to say to you:

> There's a pen on the desk.

Beginning the sentence with *There is* signals that I'm giving you information of some relevance to you.  Native speakers do this without conscious deliberate thought; it comes naturally, as it is how the language works.

The following statement under those very same circumstances would give you only the information,  not the "meta information" that it is information relevant to you in some way:

> A pen is on the desk.

That mere statement of the bald fact might sound a little terse and unfriendly and even prove momentarily puzzling to someone who is patting their pockets looking for a pen:   The puzzlement wouldn't last long, a fraction of a second. "Oh, you mean I can use that pen on the desk."

Answer (score 1):

English language learning: the best way to show the difference is to answer questions where these forms would be used.

**Typical scenarios** when learning English forms.

1) Asking questions with **what**:

Question: **What's** on the desk? [Or: What is on the desk?]
Answer: **A pen is on the desk**. [Or: A pen's on the desk.]
Answer: **There's a pen on the desk.**

2) Asking questions with "is there/are there"

Question: **Is there** a pen on the desk?
Answer: **Yes, there is**. or:  **No,there isn't**.
Answer: "A pen is on the desk" **does not answer "an is/are there" question.**

There is/are are used to make statements or ask question about a thing or situation. It is called the **existential there.** (there is is for singular. There are is for plural: There are apples on the desk)

It is explained more fully [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Existential_clause)
These sentences (or clauses as Wikipedia says) are used to indicate absence and presence. "Different languages have different ways of forming and using existential clauses [sentences or utterances]."